# How to detect bitmap picture contain muted or vibrant color?

Tags: android, bitmap, color-palette

I use `pallete` class to set random background color to `textview`, and some images cannot generate color and return color like gray. I find that some image file work with `getMutedColor` and some other work with `getVibrantColor` and others.

Here is my layout. I use `ImageView` to show bitmap and a `TextView` below it to show name with random background.

### How can we detect whether image file work with `getMutedColor` or `getVibrantColor` or others?

Here is my code I try so far:

```
public void generateColor(Bitmap mypic){
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    Palette p = Palette.from(result).generate();
    mTextView.setBackgroundColor(p.getVibrantColor(default_color));
}
```

I am appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd simply check for null.

```
public int getSwatch(Bitmap b){
    Palette p = Palette.from(b).generate();
    Palette.Swatch swatch;
    if((swatch = p.getVibrantSwatch()) != null){
        return swatch.getRgb();
    }
    if((swatch = p.getLightMutedSwatch()) != null){
        return swatch.getRgb();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    return Color.WHITE;
}
```

`Color.WHITE` at the end is the **fallback color**. Should `Palette` be unable to find a color, you will still get `WHITE` as a result. You can swap it with any color you wish.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: I work, but mostly vibrant or light vibrant and not muted. Color sometimes doesn't match with picture.

Comment: Nice, It answer my question. It would be better if you use switch case.

Comment: show me how you'd write a switch statement for this :b